# 404 requesting SyncStatus... a.k.a. Status

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

I am trying to make a query to get the SyncStatus objects that have failed.  In The API Explorer you have to choose the "Status" menu option in order to test this and submit requests to https:///sb/STATUS/v2/, even though the response XML refers to it as SyncStatus... so not really sure what it should be called exactly.

But that's not really my problem.  My problem is that when I submit a request (details below) I get a 404 error.  It works perfectly find in the API Explorer, with the exact same XML in the body.  I make other calls to the API all the time, so I know my framework is working.

Help?

REQUEST HEADERS

```
Content-Length: 322
Authorization:
OAuth
oauth_consumer_key="KEY",
oauth_nonce="NONCE",
oauth_signature="SIG",
oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",
oauth_timestamp="1377117362",
oauth_token="TOKEN",
oauth_version="1.0"
Content-Type: text/xml
Host: services.intuit.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

REQUEST BODY

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?><SyncStatusRequest ErroredObjectsOnly="true" xmlns="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/xmlrequest RestDataFilter.xsd"><OfferingId>ipp</OfferingId></SyncStatusRequest>
```

RESPONSE (with some new lines added for readability)

```
<html><head><title>JBoss Web/2.1.12.GA-patch-03 - Error report</title><style><!--H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}HR {color : #525D76;}--></style> </head>
<body>
<h1>HTTP Status 404 - Null subresource for path: https://internal.services.intuit.com/sb/status/v2/725079435</h1>
<HR size="1" noshade="noshade">
<p>
<b>type</b> 
Status report</p><p><b>message</b> <u>Null subresource for path: https://internal.services.intuit.com/sb/status/v2/725079435</u>
</p><p>
<b>description</b> 
<u>The requested resource (Null subresource for path: https://internal.services.intuit.com/sb/status/v2/725079435) is not available.</u>
</p>
<HR size="1" noshade="noshade">
<h3>JBoss Web/2.1.12.GA-patch-03</h3>
</body></html>
```

EDIT: I figured out that I was using GET instead of POST.  I have fixed that, but now I am getting a different error in the response:

NEW RESPONSE (new lines added for readability):

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<RestResponse xmlns="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2">
<Error RequestId="347b6e52b653439493b57db68250b61a">
<RequestName>ErrorRequest</RequestName>
<ProcessedTime>2013-08-21T21:57:50.693Z</ProcessedTime>
<ErrorCode>-2001</ErrorCode>
<ErrorDesc>Premature end of file.</ErrorDesc>
</Error>
</RestResponse>
```

Comment: I do NOT have to send either of those things when using the API Explorer, though.  Look at the first Post Body that Mana mentions below, just an empty <SyncStatusRequest> tag, with no mention of IDs or Types at all.  When I run that query in the API Explorer it gives me a list of ALL errored objects, no matter what the type.  This is what I want to get in my app.

Comment: In fact, in the link you gave me, it specifically says that I can make a request for the SyncStatus with this body: <TimeActivityQuery ErroredObjectsOnly="true" xmlns="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2">
</TimeActivityQuery> which will give me a list of all errored objects.  Am I missing something?

Comment: OK, I still appreciate your attention on the issue, I have had a hard time getting any real resolution for the problems that I do have with the API.  Do you have any insight on the Premature End of File error?

Answer (score 3):

Just now, I've tried the same using devkit. I'm sharing the endpoint and the post body. Please give it a try and let me know if it works for you as well.

**Required Header**

```
Content-Type: text/xml
```

**Post Body**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<SyncStatusRequest ErroredObjectsOnly="true" xmlns="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2"/>
```

Another 
**Post Body**(when I pass any Id)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<SyncStatusRequest ErroredObjectsOnly="true" xmlns="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2">
    <NgIdSet>
        <NgId>660607</NgId>
        <NgObjectType>Customer</NgObjectType>
    </NgIdSet>
</SyncStatusRequest>
```

Endpoint

```
https://services.intuit.com/sb/status/v2/657117515
```

**Java Code**

```
public void testSyncStatus(String id) {
    QBSyncStatusRequest syncStatusRequest = QBObjectFactory.getQBObject(
            context, QBSyncStatusRequest.class);
    syncStatusRequest.setErroredObjectsOnly(true);
    NgIdSet ngIdSet = new NgIdSet();
    ngIdSet.setNgId(id);
    ngIdSet.setNgObjectType(ObjectName.CUSTOMER);
    List<NgIdSet> idSets = new ArrayList<NgIdSet>();
    idSets.add(ngIdSet);
    syncStatusRequest.setNgIdSet(idSets);
    logger.debug("inside testSyncStatus");

    try {
        QBSyncStatusRequestService service = QBServiceFactory.getService(
                context, QBSyncStatusRequestService.class);
        List<QBSyncStatusResponse> response = service.getSyncStatus(
                context, syncStatusRequest);
        System.out.println(response);
        Iterator<QBSyncStatusResponse> iterator = response.iterator();

        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            QBSyncStatusResponse each = (QBSyncStatusResponse) iterator
                    .next();
            System.out.println(" Message Code - " + each.getMessageCode()
                    + " Message Desc - " + each.getMessageDesc());
        }
    } catch (QBInvalidContextException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Well, you have helped me figure out ONE of my problems.  I was using GET, not POST.  However, I am having another error now.  See my edits to the original question.

Comment: By the way, I get the same premature end of file error when I try either version of your post body, both the empty SyncStatusRequest tag and the one with an ID (using an ID that is actually in my response when I use the API Explorer)

Comment: If possible, can u plz share the code. I'm not able to reproduce this error. thanks

Comment: I am developing in Google Go, which does not have an official Intuit dev kit... so there would be a LOT of code to show.

Comment: does it have any OAuth library ? you can share the name of it and/or download link. I'll try to create a POC using Go( I don't want to miss this learning opportunity :) )
thanks